# Nunjucks. Как создавать тэги с разными атрибутами

Tags: шаблонизаторы, атрибуты

Предположим у меня есть:

```
var data=[
    {
       class:"foo1",
       value:"bar1",
       name:"bra1",
    },
    {
       class:"foo2",
       value:"bar2",
    }
];
```

Я хочу, чтобы в результате рентеринга у меня получился html:

```
<input class="foo1" value="bar1" name="bra1">
<input class="foo2" value="bar2">
```

Как мне это сделать используя шаблонизать Nunjucks

Спасибо.

Comment: Этот вопрос решался также и на stackoverflow(ENG) там найдёте вы [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48768534/how-to-dynamically-iterate-tags-attribute-with-nunjucks)

Answer (score 1):

SET = сюда вписываем данные необходимые для вывода

```
{% set
    items = [
    {
        class: 'title1',
        value: 'value1',
        name: 'name1'
    },
    {
        class: 'title2',
        value: 'value2'
    }
    ]
%}

{% import "templateDataPath/data.html" as data %}

{% for data in data.items %}
    <input class="{{data.class}}" value="{{data.value}}" name="{{data.name}}">
{% endfor %}


Out:
<input class="title1" value="value1" name="name1">
<input class="title2" value="value2" name="">
```